# Отклонённая правка

Tags: поддержка, правки, отклонённые-правки

Так как на сайте большое количество вопросов и ответов с голыми ссылками на JSFiddle и аналогичные сайты, то я решил перенести содержимое из ссылок прямо в посты. Согласно правилам link-only посты запрещены (ну, по крайней мере, не рекомендуются). Однако я столкнулся с неожиданной реакцией отдельных пользователей.

Например, вот [предложенная мной правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2058).

Пользователь [@TheDoctor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/31688/thedoctor) её отклонил и вместо этого [добавил точку в конце предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/236694/revisions).

Как это понимать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Еще с времен ХэшКода мы придерживались правила добавлять пример кода на *fiddle, а также на сам ХэшКод, если это целесообразно (листинг менее 50 строк). Скорее всего данная правка была сделана по ошибке. Поправил вопрос в том стиле, как это делалось раньше.