# Оставлять ли ссылки на fiddle при наличии сниппета?

Tags: обсуждение, сниппеты

Вопрос по [следующей правке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/104132): стоит ли оставить ссылку на fiddle?

Ответ был переформатирован редактором, появился встроенный сниппет.

Ранее нашёлся [похожий вопрос на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/85/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0/89#89), но @Grundy высказал мнение, что это слишком старый вопрос, когда ещё на so не было сниппетов - поэтому нельзя применить к текущему случаю.

Одно мнение очевидно -- это внешний ресурс, фиддл может протухнуть, да и раз есть уже сниппет от so, то это лишнее дублирование.

С другой стороны, вероятно, найдутся пользователи, которым удобнее функциональностью фиддл пользоваться, чем функциональностью so.

Comment: [Stack-Snippets vs PasteBin, jsFiddle, and JSbin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302280/stack-snippets-vs-pastebin-jsfiddle-and-jsbin)

Comment: [Suggested Edit Replacing JSFiddle with Stack Snippet, what to do?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271589/suggested-edit-replacing-jsfiddle-with-stack-snippet-what-to-do)

Comment: [Should we edit our old posts to include Stack Snippets?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/should-we-edit-our-old-posts-to-include-stack-snippets)

Comment: Хм... ответы общими бы сделали.

Comment: @val Не подумал, что такое может понадобиться. Готово, добавляйте, если видите, что можно улучшить.

Comment: Так принято делать для голосований.

Comment: _"фиддл может протухнуть"_ - не может.

Answer (score 19):

Оставить и встроенный сниппет so и ссылку на fiddle.

Мы понимаем, что это некоторое дублирование, но возможно кому-то из пользователей сайта будет удобнее воспользоваться функциональностью, которую предлагают сторонние fiddle-сайты.

В рассматриваемом конкретном примере наилучший вариант был бы "улучшить правку" с возвратом ссылки на fiddle.

Answer (score -3):

Ссылку нужно удалить:

- это внешний ресурс, ссылка может со временем поменяться или быть удалена владельцем
- излишнее дублирование: есть же встроенные средства so и они хороши

Comment: jfiddle не протухает и, вроде, не меняется. В оличие от некоторых других.